# Binding a List within a bound ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

In my WPF application I have an Observablecollection "CollOfPersons" of Persons, where each Person Object has a property "NotesOnPerson" of type

```
List<Notes>
```

(among other properties). Now I bind "CollOfPersons" to a listbox lb in code via

```
lb.ItemsSource = CollOfPersons;
```

Now I have set up a template how to display a person, namely I wrap each person in a 'Expander' and display the basic properties (e.g., Name, Age) in Expander.header, and this works fine, e.g.,

```
<Expander.Header>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    ...
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    ...
  </StackPanel>
</Expander.Header>
```

However, now I'd like to bind the NotesOnPerson list of notes to the Expander.Content. But since this is again a list of varying size I don't know how to do it. Same strategy as above does not work, because I don't know the name of the Expander (as I knew the name 'lb' of the big listbox in which all the stuff is). Something like

```
<Expander.Content>
   <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NoteTemplate}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=NotesOnPerson}"/>
</Expander.Content>
```

doesn't seem to work. I seem to be confused about code and XAML binding. How should I solve this?

Comment: Can you post the code for `NoteTemplate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<Expander.Content>
   <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NoteTemplate}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding NotesOnPerson}"/>
</Expander.Content>
```

I'm not familiar with the `Expander`, but since `NotesOnPerson` is (presumably) a property of `Person` and not of `Name`, that's the syntax you should use. (the `Path=` is optional, since just putting it in like that is another way to declare the `Path`)

Comment: Thanks, of course I should drop the 'Name.' But stil it does not work.

Comment: Oh my, after finding a stupid mistake elsewhere in the code this does work.. Thanks again, and sorry for the confusion.